# Regex syntax that matches any combo of /, /abc/,/abc/efg/, etc

Tags: regex

I can't figure out a regex that can match the following examples:

1. /
2. /abc
3. /abc/
4. /abc/xxx
5. /abc/efg/
6. /abc/efg/xxx

I need to capture each variable between the /.

**Example**: /abc/efg/xxx should return:

1. Variable 1: abc
2. Variable 2: efg
3. Variable 3: xxx

**Notes:**

1. The text between / will always be alphanumeric
2. The above 6 usecases are the only cases I'm concerned about.

Comment: Just split on `/`

Comment: You can use this `^\/(?:[a-zA-Z0-9]+\/?)*$` which will match both, ending with `/` and not ending with `/` [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qnw8YP/2)

Comment: @PushpeshKumarRajwanshi - I need to differentiate between abc/efg.  Meaning your regex captures the entire pattern, but doesn't separate the variables.  Maybe I'm asking for something that Regex is not meant to do.

Something like: ^\/(.+)\/(.+) will capture it correctly for usecase 4,5,6.  But does not handle usecases 1-3.

Demo: [https://regex101.com/r/7j4wTJ/1]

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any cleaner way than this one to solve your problem exactly as you stated it:

```
^\/(?:(\w+)(?:\/(\w+)(?:\/(\w+))?)?)?((?<!\/)\/)?$
```

You can check here : https://regex101.com/r/FJuJ43/6

Explanation :

```
starts with a /: ^\/    
rest of unstored group is optional: (?: … )?    
may ends with a / unless there is another one just before: ((?<!\/)\/)?$
in the main group, first stored alphanum only subgroup: (\w+)
followed by another optional unstored subgroup, starting with a / and followed by another alphanum only stored subgroup: (?:\/(\w+) … )?
and ditto: (?:\/(\w+))?
```

This works, creating the three groups.

But I cant prevent the last char being a trailing /

/aaa/bbb/ccc/ works as well, when it should not. If you can bear with this, you should be ok.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This solution is worked.  I realized that I had to allow '-''s as well, so I updated the regex to: ^\/(?:([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?:\/([a-zA-Z0-9-]+)(?:\/(\w+))?)?)?((?<!\/)\/)?$

Comment: @MunawarAli take care that \w is actually [a-zA-Z0-9_]. Dont forget to add the _ (if you need it of course)

Comment: @MunsterMan Hello, it would be nice of you to accept my answer if it helped you. Thanks,